# Convergence in Sup-Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, problem-solving

Given that we have sequence of piece-wise functions $S_{n}$ on [0,2] given by
$ \frac{1}{n}x+x^{2}$ for ,$ 0\leq x \leq 1$   and $\frac{1}{2n}$ for , 
$1<x \leq 2$

Whether this sequence converge in sup-metric, where sup metric distance between functions
$ d_{s}(h,g) = \underset{a \in {[0,2]}}{sup} | f(a) -g(a) |$

Now, for first two functions n=1 and 2. The distance between them by sup-metric is $0.5$ and for n=2 and 3 its $0.1667$ and it keeps on decreasing as n increases to infinity. Is this true, and how we can prove its convergence formally. I am not sure how to identify the limiting function in this sequence.

we have to show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n >N$ it is true that sup-metric $d_{s} (f_{n}, f_{0}) < \varepsilon$ where $f_{0}$ is the limiting function in the sequence.

Comment: What are $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1nx+x^2\right)$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac1{2n}$?

Comment: The $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{x}x+x^{2}) = x^{2}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{2n})=0$

Comment: Exactly. And that gives you the only possible candidate for the limit function; now you just have to see whether the functions $S_n$ actually do converge to it in the sup metric.

Comment: Yes, but i am struggling to show the formal proof. I have done the proof of point-wise convergence. which is  $f_{0}(x) =  0$ if $x= 0$ ;  $1$ if $x=1$; $0$ if $1<x \leq2$ and $x^{2}$ if $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 2):

You have the pointwise limit

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2,&\text{if }0\le x\le 1\\
0,&\text{if }1<x\le 2\;,
\end{cases}$$

so you just need to see whether the functions $S_n$ converge to $f$ in the sup metric. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have

$$d_s(S_n,f)=\sup_{x\in[0,2]}|S_n(x)-f(x)|\;,$$

where

$$|S_n(x)-f(x)|=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}n,&\text{if }0\le x\le 1\\
\frac1{2n},&\text{if }1<x\le 2\;.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $\frac{x}n$ is increasing on the interval $[0,1]$, so $\frac{x}n\le\frac1n$ on $[0,1]$ with equality at $x=1$, and since $\frac1{2n}<\frac1n$, it follows that $d_s(S_n,f)=\frac1n$. Thus,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_s(S_n,f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0\;,$$

and $f$ is also the limit of the sequence $\langle S_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ in the sup metric.